# How to change CSS value with a returned validation error

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

I have a scenario I will try to explain, sorry for my English.

I have created a form to submit some values , within the form user can select an option, but one option of which it is "**Others specify...**" when it is selected the hidden **textarea** is ***displayed*** and user can fill in some data. For the case that it is selected and user does not fill any data, the form is returned back due to validation failure but the **textarea** is no longer **visible** because `onchange="selectOption();"` is not triggered. Everything works fine but in my case I am trying to make the **textarea** visible with validation error message when it is returned back. How do I perfom this.

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{route('employer-section-b.store')}}"> @csrf <div class="col-md-12">
<select name="b3" id="sector" class="form-control @error('b3') is-invalid @enderror" onchange="selectOption();">
          <option value="" disabled selected>select</option>
          <option value="1" @if (old('b3')=="1" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Agriculture, forestry, and fishing </option>
          <option value="2" @if (old('b3')=="2" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Mining and quarrying</option>
          <option value="14" @if (old('b3')=="3" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Others specify……</option></select>
       
      <div class="col-md-12 mt-2" id="specify" style="display: none">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <textarea rows="2" name="b3" class="form-control @error('b3') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="Type here..">
            {{ old('b3') }}</textarea>
        </div></div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Script to diplay textarea if others is selected

```
<script>
  function selectOption() {
    var sector = document.getElementById("sector").value;
    var y = document.querySelector("#specify");
    if (sector == 3) {
      y.removeAttribute("style")
    } else if (sector != 3) {
      y.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `setAttribtue` is the completely wrong way to add a style. Just use `element.style.display = 'none';`. However, smart and modern developers will add/remove/toggle CSS classes with `classList`. By taking the right approach your whole issues and the connected questions would resolve or change.

Comment: Thanks @tacoshy for the quick answer, if possible can I get a snippet for the approach you suggest. Appreciation in advance

Comment: Currently sitting in a bus. I just noticed that you also miss a closing `</select>`-tag. The approach is simple: `if (sector == 3) { y.classList.remove('d-none); } else { y.classList.add('d-none); }` Then simply disable the submit button if the textarea is empty or not.

Comment: Thanks for your well explanations, that is working fine, but for my scenario as explained above I want also to show the **textarea** when **validation error is returned**. Because when error is retuned I can only see `Other  Specify`  as selected but the **textarea** is **invisible** . How do I make the textarea also visible when validation error is returned. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you post a working [repro]?

Comment: Can you show us which code interacts with the page when the validation error is returned?

Comment: Thanks @WaterMan, actually I don't know how to handle this, that's why I am looking for help.

Comment: @tacoshy there's nothing inherently wrong with using `setAttribute` to **set** the value of the style **attribute**. If I were using plain vanilla JS without classes I'd certainly do it that way instead of using the old DOM 0 properties. But as you say, toggling classes is how it's generally done these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not explicitly showing the `textarea` when the `b3` option with value `3` is selected ? This way, changing the `JS` code is no longer needed.

Se the example below:

> You have a duplicate name in use, `b3`, so i have changed the second duplicate found on the `textarea` to `b4`.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('employer-section-b.store') }}"> 
  @csrf
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <select name="b3" id="sector" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('b3') ? ' is-invalid':'' }}" onchange="selectOption()">
      <option value="" disabled selected>select</option>
      <option value="1"{{ old('b3') == 1 ? ' selected':'' }}>Agriculture, forestry, and fishing </option>
      <option value="2"{{ old('b3') == 2 ? ' selected':'' }}>Mining and quarrying</option>
      <option value="3"{{ old('b3') == 3 ? ' selected':'' }}>Others specify……</option>
    </select>
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-2" id="specify"{!! ($hasB4Error = $errors->has('b4') || old('b3') == 3) ? '':' style="display: none"' !!}>
      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <textarea rows="2" name="b4" class="form-control{{ $hasB4Error ? ' is-invalid':'' }}" placeholder="Type here..">{{ old('b3') }}</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

> `{!! $errors->has('b4') || old('b3') == 3 ? '':' style="display: none"' !!}`

This line of code does the trick, it tells `Blade` to only place the `CSS` that hides the `textarea` only when no errors found on `b3` nor `b4` elements.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is when you submit the form, the page is reloaded and all the form data is reset.

What you should do is create a `submit` event listener in javascript, and run
`event.preventDefault()` to stop the form from reloading the page, and then handle what would happen if the form was submitted when the text area is empty.

```javascript
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    // Prevent form from reloading the page
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get content written inside textarea
    let textareaValue = document.querySelector('.form-floating > .form-control').value;

    // Check if textarea is empty
    if (!textareaValue.trim()) {
        // Show a message to the user that an error has occured
        console.log('Validation error');
    } else {
        // Route to "employer-section-b.store"
        route('employer-section-b.store');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would you use `.form-floating > .form-control` – which is wrong – when the element you want has a name attribute?

Comment: I'm just showing him an example of what he would want to do, he can change it to whatever he wants later

Comment: Thanks @WaterMan for this approach, with this **snippet**  I need to add an if statement first to check `if (sector == 3)` before starting  `!textareaValue.trim()` to avoid checking `textarea` even though `sector == 1 || sector == 2` is selected.